# Taylor series- help!

Tags: taylor-expansion

$f(x)$ is twice differentiable function in $[0,1]$.

we know that: $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$, $f'(0)=f'(1)=0$.

show that there exists a point $c$ such that $\left|f''(c)\right|\ge 4$

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. What have you done so far?   

2. You should put a more meaningful title.

Comment: @user121110 Disregard those people that ask you for what you have done etc. Soon you will be given an answer/hints.

Comment: Haha! And there are people voting to close. Ridiculous people.

Answer (score 2):

By Taylor's theorem, there are $\xi\in(0,\frac{1}{2}),\eta\in(\frac{1}{2},1)$ s.t.

$$f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=f(0)+f'(0)\left(\frac{1}{2}-0\right)+\frac{f''(\xi)}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}-0\right)^2=\frac{f''(\xi)}{8}$$

$$f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=
f(1)+f'(1)\left(\frac{1}{2}-1\right)+\frac{f''(\eta)}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}-1\right)^2=1+\frac{f''(\eta)}{8}$$

Then we have

$$0=1+\frac{1}{8}(f''(\eta)-f''(\xi))$$
 which implies

$$8=f''(\xi)-f''(\eta)\leq|f''(\xi)|+|f''(\eta)|\leq 2\max\{|f''(\xi)|,|f''(\eta)|\}$$

Then we have either $|f''(\xi)|\geq 4$ or $|f''(\eta)|\geq 4$